# unable to float nav menu to the right in a plain html header

Tags: css, html

I'm writing a simple code to design a plain header with a logo and navigation menu inside it. I want my logo to be on left and navigation menu to be on right side. It looks like a child problem but I am unable to resolve this issue.

I have tried to make all possible tweaking in my IDE as well as Chrome Inspection but couldn't figure it out.

My Index.html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PSD to Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- body content -->
    <header class="secondary-sky-blue-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="#" class="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                </a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and style.css is

```
header {
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
header a.logo{
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100px;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header nav ul li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I have a reset.css also

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #777;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.primary{
    color: #e74c3c;
}

.primary-bg{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.secondary-dark-blue
{
    color: #34495e;
}

.secondary-dark-blue-bg
{
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.secondary-sky-blue
{
    color: #2d82d8;
}

.secondary-sky-blue-bg
{
    background-color: #2d82d8;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I am expecting the nav menu to float on right but it is not working.

Comment: I didn't find the class "menu" in your html code. Did you forget it?

Comment: @Rajesh Are you using bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4

Comment: You can add class="pull-right" it will bring nav to the right position

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a menu class defined. Are you trying to use nav if so it should be

nav {float:right;}

Comment: did you set a width of the nav? If the nav + the logo is larger than the width of the container the nav will go below the logo. Also the way you have your <li> setup it will be vertical not horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code that you are defining class `.menu` in your css but you are not using it anywhere in your html.
And you can do it in better way by using flexbox.

```
.row{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: between;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It was the real problem but display:block working for me. Appreciate your help to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It not that much heard as i have review your code you have to add simple one class to your nav tag and that is nav class="pull-right" use class pull-right, it is default bootstrap class.

Answer (score 0):

I am here to answer my own question. I found this piece of code in default bootstrap file

```
.row {
display: flex;}
```

I changed it to `display:block` and it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I respect all the answers but if you using Bootstrap 4 just give `ml-auto` class to nav it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
.row {
    display: block;
    justify-content: between;
}
```

in your reset.css or style.css
or

```
<nav class="ml-auto">
```

in your index.html will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**You must use `col-md-12` inside the `row`**. I have used flex property for `nav` and `margin-left:auto` to align the menu right side.

Optionally you can use floating method with clearfix to align the menu right side.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

header a.logo {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100px;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header nav ul li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}


/** second css **/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #777;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.primary {
    color: #e74c3c;
}

.primary-bg {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.secondary-dark-blue {
    color: #34495e;
}

.secondary-dark-blue-bg {
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.secondary-sky-blue {
    color: #2d82d8;
}

.secondary-sky-blue-bg {
    background-color: #2d82d8;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,400" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" >
<header class="secondary-sky-blue-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <nav>
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```